# csh script not finding executable

Tags: shell, executable, csh

For the current project, I need to run the GENESIS genetic algorithm program, and the professor has provided a csh script that allows us to easily pass in the fitness function as well as external initilization and template files.

The script calls the makefile to build the executable, adding the fitness function to the mix and produces an executable `ga.FIT`, where FIT is the name of the finess function source file.

On the machines at school runnung Ubuntu 10.04, there is no problem whatsoever running this script.  However, when I try to run it on my machine, I get the following output:

```
./go cancer2 ex0
Note: Genesis files modified for use on USM Linux cluster
Note2: ga.cancer2 is your executable (e.g., if you need to use the debugger)
making executables ...
make: `ga.cancer2' is up to date.
make: `report' is up to date.
running ga.cancer2 ex0 ...
ga.cancer2: Command not found.
```

But the executable IS there!  I can manually call it separately via `ga.cancer2 ex0` and it runs at both the csh and bash prompts.  I've verified its not a permissions issue as the equivalent of `chmod 755` has been set to the executable.

Is this something specific to csh, and should I look into modifying the script for bash, or stick to remoting in to the school system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `ga.cancer2` is in your current directory.  Basile's answer should work, but it's probably a better idea to modify the script so it invokes `./ga.cancer2` rather than `ga.cancer2`.

In general, having `.` in your `$PATH` is a potential security risk (regardless of which shell you're using).  Imagine `cd`ing into a directory in which someone has planted an `ls` command that does something evil.  If you make sure `.` isn't in your `$PATH` (and get into the habit of typing `./command` to execute a command in your current directory), you avoid this risk.

Having `.` at the *end* of `$PATH` is less risky -- but since the most common name for a test program is `test`, and `test` will invoke `/bin/test`, the `./command` habit is still a good one.

And Basile has a good point that `csh` is not the best shell for writing scripts -- but from the looks of the output, the script you're running is probably simple enough that it doesn't make much difference.  Still, good habits and all that.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need to add `.` to your `$PATH`.

And once you've got your exam, tell your professor about the famous [C-shell considered harmful](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/) paper, and suggest him to read the [Wikipedia "Considered Harmful"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Considered_harmful) page.

Comment: Or better, modify the script to invoke `./ga.cancer2` rather than `ga.cancer2`, so you don't have to add `.` to your `$PATH`.

Comment: @Keith, that was the solution.  If you change this comment to an answer, I'll be able to accept it as the solution.  @ Basile, Nice source and will check that out when crunch time is over.